# HTML: Can I hyperlink to a separate webpage first then have it immediately redirect to another webpage?

Tags: html, hyperlink, query-string

So I have a web page that hyperlinks to this second, separate site. But the link that I'm using depends on whether or not a session has been made to the second site in the first place and won't work for instance if I went into incognito mode (I retrieved the URL from the live header request in Dev tools). I'm doing this because I want to push values into checkboxes on the second site. I don't know enough about query strings to get what I want. I have the parameter IDs of what I want to change but for some reason, setting the values in the query string isn't working.

So the only thing that I think can work is a hyperlink that goes to the main web page and starts a session, before redirecting to the page I want with the live header request link. Any ideas?

Comment: You could add an iframe and use JS to change the target? Or pop the first link open as a new tab, and then (again probably using JS) direct the main tab to the second site?
Thankfully there's no way to make someone elses site redirect to another place (unless you want to chat on SF/SU about proxies ;))

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I think I can do this: <a href="site.com/page1" target="nameforfirstpage">first</a>. Then just do it again, but change it to <a href="site.com/page2" target="nameforfirstpage">google</a>